# Remove closed brackets java

Tags: java, regex

Hi guys i have a a string like this

```
String main = "Sandy \"children\":[]"
String foo = "\"children\":[]";

main = main.replaceAll(foo, "");
```

If I want to replace the whole foo in main with a single character "" then what regex I need to use?

I ll be having a json data like this i need to replace all the empty children object

```
{"data" : "Search engines",
                    "children":[ {
                    "data":"Yahoo","children":[{"data":"1","children":[{}]}]},
                    {"data":"Bing","children":[{"data":"2","children":[]}]},{"data":"Bing2"},{"data":"Bing3"},{"data":"Bing4"},{"data":"Bing5"},{"data":"Bing6"},{"data":"Bing7"},{"data":"Bing34"}]                    
                    }
```

Comment: `""` isn't a single character - it's an empty string.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the empty children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, now you've given more information, I would thoroughly recommend *not* using regular expressions for this. Parse the JSON and use the DOM representation of it instead. Otherwise there are bound to be ways of fooling whatever you use. Text representations like this are simply not a good match for regular expressions IMO.

---

(Original answer...)

It's not clear why you're using `replaceAll` and regular expressions in the first place.

I suspect you just want:

```
main = main.replace(foo, "");
```

That will treat `foo` as a normal string, not a regular expression. Unless you really *want* to use a regular expression, use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`.

Comment: actually i ll be having whole lot of paranthesis in my actual string

Comment: @karthick: But do you actually want to treat them as a regular expression or not? Currently your question is very unclear. Giving some sample inputs and desired outputs would be useful.

Comment: @@Jon: Sorry jon i understood your point thanks for explaining

Comment: @karthick: Have edited my answer - basically, don't do this. Use a JSON parser instead. Btw, you don't need to use "@@". Just "@Jon" will  notify me... (or not even that, when you're adding a comment to my answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Pattern.quote(String)` to ensure everything is counted as literal in the regex

```
main = main.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(foo), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question still and parsing as JSON, then manipulating as JavaScript might be the answer... but if you want to turn this:

```
{"data" : "Search engines",
                "children":[ {
                "data":"Yahoo","children":[{"data":"1","children":[{}]}]},
                {"data":"Bing","children":[{"data":"2","children":[]}]},{"data":"Bing2"},{"data":"Bing3"},{"data":"Bing4"},{"data":"Bing5"},{"data":"Bing6"},{"data":"Bing7"},{"data":"Bing34"}]                    
                }
```

into this:

```
{"data" : "Search engines",
                "children":[ {
                "data":"Yahoo","children":[{"data":"1"}]},
                {"data":"Bing","children":[{"data":"2"}]},{"data":"Bing2"},{"data":"Bing3"},{"data":"Bing4"},{"data":"Bing5"},{"data":"Bing6"},{"data":"Bing7"},{"data":"Bing34"}]                    
                }
```

Then use this expression:

```
",?\"children\":\\[(\\{\\})?]"
```

as in the following code (Wow, I think this is right, but it's been a while...):

```
String main = "Sandy \"children\":[]"
String foo = ",?\"children\":\\[(\\{\\})?]";

main = main.replaceAll(foo, "");
//main == "Sandy "
```